# How to export data from Cassandra to mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, cassandra, export, apache-storm

I am using Apache (Kafka-Storm-Cassandra) for real time processing.The problem I am facing is that I can't use aggregation queries on Cassandra directly(Datastax can be used but it is a paid service).Moreover, I also considered using mongodb but It is not good for more and frequent writes. So, I am thinking to do all my calculation in storm and store it into Cassandra and move it on hourly basis or so to mongodb to perform my further analytics.

Is this the right approach or are there any better options to achieve this ?

```
Also, How can I export data directly from Cassandra to mongodb prefebly using JAVA?
```

Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing your full requirement, amount of inserts/updates one cannot predict is it a good or bad approach. Mongo is less preferable for heavy writes but it can support quite a good no. of inserts. So important thing is how many writes you have per unit time and based on that you can take the decision.

I have seen Mongo taking upto 1000-2000 writes per sec with avg of 4-5ms on server class machines. Of course Cassandra beats it by margin but if you need to perform any aggregation then Mongo has better framework and capabilities.

For export and import, flat csv can be used.
Cassandra can export data to csv and MongoDB can import data from csv with export/import options.

Check [MongoImport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) and for exporting from cassandra, 
example could be,

```
copy employee (emp_id, dept, designation, emp_name, salary)
 to 'employee.csv';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I need to design a system which tracks the user activity on an eCommerce website.  The number of writes will totally depend on the user traffic on the site .So for now I am not sure about the number of writes per second.

Comment: You dont need the exact no. you can monitor the traffic for a period of time (a day or a week) and then you can find out what is peak hour load. If your application is not big enough then I think you will be having less than 100-200 writes/sec. If that's the case then MongoDB alone is enough for you. That will save your export/import time and will allow aggregation queries. But remember if you run aggregation queries during working hours your query time/processing time will increase and can hamper performance. Best way is to process aggregation queries overnight or when load is minimal.

Comment: For now we have only few clients(only 2) so number of writes are less at this point of time.But we are expecting more clients so we don't want to reach a point from where we need to roll back and break our existing system. And aggregation queries  will be run by the clients to check the analytics report (something like google analytics report)on there page so that is not under our control.

Comment: From my understanding till now,  I think best design is create a cluster of MongoDB servers. though currently you have 2 users but suppose in future it increases to 1K-10K users still based on distribution I dont think per sec insert/updates will increase 1000. This means your insert/update is problem is resolved for quite a time (if it increases more than assumed value you need to increase cluster size/partition the collection). In cluster, use some replicas only for aggregation queries with a intermediate sync factor which wont overhead this replica servers with sync issues.

Comment: This will serve your analytics report queries. I hope you understand design suggested.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please upvote if you find the answer useful :)

Comment: Is the aggregation advantage still true in 2020?